# Selenium webdriver code for reading/Writing data from CSV in Python

Tags: python, csv, selenium, screenshot

Can someone let me know 
1. How to write selenium webdriver code in python for reading the data from CSV files and input them into fields of application under test and print the results into CSV file after execution.
2. I have written capture screenshot for every statement to get the screenshots.
Is there any that we can capture screenshots in a single go, like using any loop statements etc..If yes, then can you post the code

Thanks for your time and response is appreciated....

Answer (score 1):

1. Selenium tests in Python are just python code. You can use the CSV module and  a normal loop to carry out these actions on the page, and receive the values from the new DOM.
2. You can use loops just like normal Python to capture the screenshots, but no I'm not going to write the code for ya.